# How to create a new Stream based on another Stream's data in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I have created a stream which returns a List of specific documents containing a specific field from Firestore. Based on this Stream, I want to create another stream that uses the data from the first stream, to retrieve some other data from Firestore. How is this possible?

This is the stream

```
Stream<List<EsportsMatch>> get csgoMatches {
  String formattedDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.now());

  print(formattedDate);

  return db
      .collection("matches")
      .where("@type", isEqualTo: "CS GO")
      .snapshots()
      .map((_csgoMatchesFromSnapshot));
}
```